# Facebook Graph get Full Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the list of all my friends with `me?fields=friendlists&locale=it_IT` but I get only the ID and not his name. How can I get it ?

One more question... Once I know the id of my friends how can I get their profile pictures ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of friends and their names using:

```
/me?fields=friends&locale=it_IT
```

Or

```
/me/friends?fields=name
```

Then, to show their profile picture, just do the following in your HTML code (replace `{friend_id}` with friend's ID):

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{friend_id}/picture" />
```

Comment: I tried it in the graph API explorer and it gives me the ids AND my name

Comment: can you tell me what tokens should I use because it give me this "{
  "data": [
  ]
}"

Comment: The new Graph API (v2.0+) only gives you list of friends that also use your application. Please see link: https://www.webniraj.com/2014/06/12/facebook-api-getting-friends-using-graph-api-2-0-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/

Comment: You have to use taggable_friends Thank You